# Getting next class of a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

Alright so basically I am trying to get the class of next div element that is outside the current element and append to it. I've had various attempts but couldnt actually get any good result. I want to append to only the next class and not all of them

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="reveal-options">Click me</a>
    <div class="hidden"></div>
</div>  
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="reveal-options">Click me</a>
    <div class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".reveal-options").on("hover",function() {
    $('.reveal-options').closest('.hidden').css({"display":"block"});   
});
```

This jquery is innacurate for some reason

**EDIT:** I cant use next since in some cases reveal-options will hold some data such as div or such

Comment: You say you wish to find the class of the next div outside of the element ... and then append to it ... but you don't try to "find the clas" of the next div , neither do you go up one level using parent ... so what is it you exactly want .. please specify clearly with an example ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
 $(".reveal-options").on("hover",function() {
    $(this).next('.hidden').css({"display":"block"});   
});
```

Comment: I cant use next since sometimes reveal-options contains some informations

Comment: then what is the issue with information. the next div remains the same.

Comment: @TomislavNikolic You say "i can't use next"  but accepted solution with next.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
$(".reveal-options").on("hover",function() {
    $('.reveal-options').next('.hidden').css({"display":"block"});   
});
```